# EF is duplicating columns in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem in EF, it is duplicating column like 'MenuPai_Id' and 'MenuPai_Id1',
here are the classes.

```
public class Menu :EntidadePadrao
{
    public int? MenuPai_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Menu MenuPai { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> MenusFilhos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PerfilUsuarioMenu> PerfisUsuario { get; set; }
}

public class MenuMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Menu>
{
    public MenuMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);           
        this.ToTable("Menu");
        this.Property(t => t.MenuPai_Id).HasColumnName("MenuPai_Id");

        this.HasOptional(t => t.MenuPai)
            .WithMany(t => t.MenusFilhos)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MenuPai_Id);
    }
}
```

And this is the sql generated for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menus] (
[Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Sequencia] [int] NOT NULL,   
[MenuPai_Id] [int],   
[MenuPai_Id1] [int],
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Menus] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Menus] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Menus_dbo.Menus_MenuPai_Id1]
FOREIGN KEY ([MenuPai_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Menus] ([Id])
```

I have other mappings like this in the project, that was generated automatically and it's working fine. Just this class I added manually and I can't find why doesn't work at the same way.

I appreciate any help.

Edited: 
I just forgot this:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MenuMap());
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but are you actually using `MenuMap`? Can you show the code that adds it to `DbModelBuilder.Configurations`?

Comment: It's very silly, but that was the problem. Thank you. I lost 3 hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuId` shouldn't be *nullable* since it is a primary key,

```
public class Menu :EntidadePadrao
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public int MenuPai_ID {get; set; }

    // Navigation List
    public Menu MenuPai { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Menu> MenusFilhos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PerfilUsuarioMenu> PerfisUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

then in your configuration, tell EF that `MenuPai_ID` is *nullable*.

```
public MenuMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.MenuId);

    // Property and Mapping
    this.ToTable("Menu");

    this.Property(t => t.MenuPai_ID)
        .IsOptional()
        .HasColumnName("MenuPai_ID");

    // Relationship
    this.HasOptional(t => t.MenuPai)
        .WithMany(t => t.MenusFilhos)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.MenuPai_Id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I always used nullable together with HasOptional, I'll change. But the problem was I did not use the MenuMap, just stupid error.

Comment: `MenuPai_Id` isn't the primary key, and for nullable foreign keys, mapping them to `int?` is correct. In fact, what you're doing now, continuing to mark `MenuPai_ID` as optional but mapping it to the non-nullable `int` type, is very likely to be wrong: how would you represent `NULL`?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the answer. MenuPai_Id is not primary key and is not optional. And for optional foreign key I'll keep using nullable int.